# sysUpTime.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysUpTime)

Tags: 22.04, snmp

I've installed these snmp Ubuntu packages :

snmp snmpd php-snmp libsnmp-base libsnmp-dev

I have the following paramters :

```bash
$ sudo egrep "^agentaddress|rocommunity" /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
agentaddress udp:161
# rocommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-only access community name
#rocommunity  public default -V systemonly
#rocommunity6 public default -V systemonly
```

and created a snmp user :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl stop snmpd
$ sudo net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -a MD5 -x AES svc_snmp
$ sudo egrep "^(rouser|createUser)" /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf /usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf
/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf:rouser svc_snmp
$
```

When I test, I get this :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl start snmpd
$ snmpget -v3 -u svc_snmp -l authNoPriv -A $MDP_SNMP -a MD5 localhost sysUpTime.0
sysUpTime.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> sysUpTime)
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @jiveturkey I think I was missing the [`snmp-mibs-downloader`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/snmp-mibs-downloader) package which downloads the MIB files.